# PyBuffer_New: Do I need to free manually?

Tags: memory-leaks, cython, pybuffer

I am searching for a memory leak in code of someone else. I found:

```
def current(self):
    ...
    data = PyBuffer_New(buflen)
    PyObject_AsCharBuffer(data, &data_ptr, &buflen)
    ...
    return VideoFrame(data, self.frame_size, self.frame_mode,
                      timestamp=<double>self.frame.pts/<double>AV_TIME_BASE,
                      frameno=self.frame.display_picture_number)


cdef class VideoFrame:
    def __init__(self, data, size, mode, timestamp=0, frameno=0):
        self.data = data
        ...
```

In function `current()` is no `free` or similar, neither in `VideoFrame`. Is the `PyBuffer` automatically freed when the `VideoFrame` object gets deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: "it depends; we don't have enough code to tell from your question." It's governed by what type you've told Cython that `PyBuffer_New` returns. I'll give two simplified illustrating cases and hopefully you should be able to work it out for your more complicated case.

If you tell Cython that it's a `PyObject*` it has no innate knowledge of that type, and doesn't do anything to keep track of the memory:

```
# BAD - memory leak!

cdef extern from "Python.h":
    ctypedef struct PyObject
    PyObject* PyBuffer_New(int size)

def test():
    cdef int i
    for i in range(100000): # call lots of times to allocate lots of memory
        # (type of a is automatically inferred to be PyObject*
        # to match the function definition)
        a = PyBuffer_New(1000)
```

and the generated code for the loop pretty much looks like:

```
for (__pyx_t_1 = 0; __pyx_t_1 < 1000; __pyx_t_1+=1) {
  __pyx_v_i = __pyx_t_1;
  __pyx_v_a = PyBuffer_New(1000);
}
```

i.e. memory is being allocated but never freed. If you run `test()` and look at a task manager you can see the memory usage jump up and not return.

Alternatively, if you tell Cython it's an `object` that lets Cython deal with it like any other Python object, and manage the reference count correctly:

```
# Good - no memory leak

cdef extern from "Python.h":
    object PyBuffer_New(int size)

def test():
    cdef int i
    for i in range(100000):# call lots of times to allocate lots of memory
        a = PyBuffer_New(1000)
```

The generated code for the loop is then

```
for (__pyx_t_1 = 0; __pyx_t_1 < 100000; __pyx_t_1+=1) {
  __pyx_v_i = __pyx_t_1;
  __pyx_t_2 = PyBuffer_New(1000); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 7; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
    __Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_2);
    __Pyx_XDECREF_SET(__pyx_v_a, __pyx_t_2);
    __pyx_t_2 = 0;
}
```

Note the `DECREF`, which will be where the object is deallocated. If you run `test()` here you see no long-term jump in memory usage.

It may be possible to jump between these two cases by using `cdef` for variable (for example in the definition of `VideoFrame`). If they use `PyObject*` without careful `DECREF`s then they're probably leaking memory...

Comment: thanks! It seems the author has implemented the "correct" `object PyBuffer_New(int size)` way. Also I see that in `VideoFrame` `data` is defined as `cdef readonly object data` . Is that the case where it could leak?

Comment: Just found that  `__Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_2);` is called in the C-file after `PyBuffer_New`. So I suppose everything is correctly implemented.

Comment: @P.R. I can't see anything I'm immediately suspicious of (including for `VideoFrame.data`). Although obviously it's hard to tell from this. The tool of choice for finding memory leaks (on Linux at least) is Valgrind. It's been a while since I made real use of it though, so I can't give any real advice.